# Understanding the use of compactness in getting a variation of an admissible curve from a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I came across the following result in the book "Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature" by John Lee.

> **Theorem:** Let $\gamma: \left[ a, b \right] \rightarrow M$ be an admissible curve and $V$ be a vector field along $\gamma$. Then, $V$ is the variation field of some variation of $\gamma$. Moreover, if $V$ is proper then the variation can be chosen to be proper.

The proof of this result uses the fact that $\left[ a, b \right]$ is compact. Particularly, this is used to define the variation of $\gamma$ as $\Gamma \left( s, t \right) = \exp \left( s V(t) \right)$. I am  not sure if I understand this properly. Here are my thoughts on how it is used.

We know that $\exp$ is defined on an open set containing the zero section. That is, there is an open set $\mathscr{E} \subseteq TM$ (the tangent bundle) such that for all $p \in M$, $\left( p, 0 \right) \in \mathscr{E}$. Therefore, for each $p \in M$, there are balls $B^{\left( p \right)} \left( 0, \delta_p \right) \subseteq \mathscr{E} \cap T_pM$. Now, we see that $V(t) \in \frac{2 \| V(t) \|}{\delta_p} B \left( 0, \delta_p \right)$ so that these (scaled) balls form an open cover for $V \left( \left[ a, b \right] \right)$ (am I right here?). Once this is done, we get a finite subcover and hence there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for $\left| s \right| < \epsilon$, we have $s V(t) \in \mathscr{E} \cap T_{\gamma \left( t \right)} M$.

Is this reasoning correct? It seems to me that there will be some *disjoint* unions involved and we may not be able to use the scaled balls to conclude what we want. Any thoughts about this are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning here is awkward; the following statement does not logically follow from the covering you construct without further spelling how you choose $\epsilon$.

> hence there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for $|s|< \epsilon$, we have $sV(t) \in \mathscr{C} \cap T_{\gamma(t)}M$.

It's not clear why you decide to scale each of these balls. Your argument could be fixed in a couple of ways with more careful consideration (you are essentially trying to reprove a common lemma), but I think it is most helpful to illustrate what Lee is likely thinking here.

---

There exists an open set $\mathscr{C} \subseteq TM$ containing the zero-section on which the exponential function $\exp \colon \mathscr{C} \to M$ is defined. Consider the map $g \colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to TM$ given by $g(s,t) = sV(t)$. Then the preimage $g^{-1}(\mathscr{C})$ is an open set containing the compact set $I = \{0\} \times [a,b]$.

By the [tube lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma), there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \times [a,b] \subseteq g^{-1}(\mathscr{C})$. Then on this set one may define $\exp \circ \, g$.